# SwiftUI - How do I create a Picker that selects values from a property?

Tags: arrays, properties, swiftui, picker

I have these two models, the first one:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class FolderModel : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject  {

    var id = UUID()
    var folderName : String
    var values : [ValueModel] = []
    
    init(folderName: String) {
        self.folderName = folderName
    }
}
```

And the second one:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ValueModel : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject, Comparable {

    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var notes : String?
    var expires : Date?
    
    init(name: String, notes: String?, expires: Date?) {
        self.name = name
        self.notes = notes
        self.expires = expires
    }
}
```

And these storages:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataManager : Equatable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {


static let shared = DataManager()

@Published var storageValues : [ValueModel] = []
typealias StorageValues = [ValueModel]


@Published var storageFolder : [FolderModel] = []
typealias StorageFolder = [FolderModel]

//The rest of the code
}
```

And then I have a Detail View of the Value, which shows all of his properties. From there, I would like to select the folder that the user wants to put it in (which in code translates to appending that value into the array "values" of the FolderModel).
To do this, I tried to create a Picker that display all the folders (by name) and that can be selected, so that when I press "Save", I can do something like "selectedFolder.append(value)". The Picker I tried to create is this:

```
import SwiftUI
struct DetailValueView: View {

@ObservedObject var dm : DataManager
@State private var selector = 0
@State var selectedFolder : FolderModel?

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Properties")) {
                folderCell
                if hasFolder == true {
                picker
                }
            }
        }
    }

var folderCell : some View {
    VStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $hasFolder) {
            if hasFolder == true {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Folder: " + "//Here I would like to display the selected value")
                }
            } else if hasFolder == false {
                Text("Folder")
            }
        }
   }
}

var picker : some View {
    Picker(selection: $selector, label: Text("Select Folder")) {
        ForEach(dm.storageFolder) { foldersForEach in
              Button(action: {
                  selectedFolder = foldersForEach
              }, label: {
                  Text(foldersForEach.folderName)
              })
        }
    }.pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
}
```

I tried to find a solution online but I don't really understand how the Picker works, I don't understand how to use that "@State private var selector = 0" to get the value that I want.
Thanks to everyone who will help me!

Comment: what is ValueModel?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste the code for ValueModel. I fixed it, I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to stress here: First, you need to either wrap your form in a NavigationView or change the picker style to `WheelPickerStyle`. Otherwise the picker won't work (see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/pickers-in-forms) for a detailed explanation). Second, your state `selector` is of type integer. So make sure to loop through integers as well. Now your state `selector` holds the index of the selected folder from the list of folders.

Please see my working example below:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager
    @State private var selector = 0
    @State private var hasFolder = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Properties")) {
                    folderCell
                    if !dm.storageFolder.isEmpty {
                    picker
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var folderCell : some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $hasFolder) {
                if hasFolder == true {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Folder: \(dm.storageFolder[selector].folderName)")
                    }
                } else if hasFolder == false {
                    Text("Folder")
                }
            }
       }
    }

    var picker : some View {
        Picker(selection: $selector, label: Text("Select Folder")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< dm.storageFolder.count) {
                Text(dm.storageFolder[$0].folderName)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
    }
}
```